# Vuetify layout with scrollbar

Tags: vue.js, layout, vuetify.js

I have a problem I can't solve in vue and vuetify. I have 2 rows, and the upper row is fixed size, because the data there is fix. But in the 2nd row I have 2 columns which are data tables, and the data can be long, but i want to display all, not just a few lines. So I want to achieve, when the lower row become higher than the height of the window a scrollbar appear just in the v-flex/v-card.

Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgKERm

```
<div id="app" style="height:100vh">
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-layout column>
      <v-flex style="background-color:red" fill-height>
        <v-card class="ma-3">
          <v-data-table :items="items" hide-actions>
            <template v-slot:items="props">
              <td>{{props.item.name}}</td>
              <td>{{props.item.value}}</td>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-layout row fill-height>
          <v-flex xs6 style="background-color:blue" fill-height>
            <v-card class="ma-3">
              <v-data-table :items="longerItem" hide-actions>
                <template v-slot:items="props">
              <td>{{props.item.name}}</td>
              <td>{{props.item.value}}</td>
            </template>
              </v-data-table>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs6 style="background-color:green" fill-height>
            <v-card class="ma-3">
              <v-data-table :items="longerItem" hide-actions>
                <template v-slot:items="props">
              <td>{{props.item.name}}</td>
              <td>{{props.item.value}}</td>
            </template>
              </v-data-table>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

The other problem is that it's not responsive. The 2nd row 2nd column doesn't go under the 2nd row 1st column when resizing.

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Also I did not quite get your second problem

Comment: I could solve it. the problem was the v-flex had ma-2 prop and thats why those flex-es were bigger than intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add overflow:auto to line 14 of your code. I hope I got your question right. (Or you can add a class to your css and use that instead of using style directly)

```
          <v-flex xs12 style="overflow:auto">
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can i make the two lower v-flex scroll individually?